# How to create modal dialog with image

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have this very simple modal dialog:

```
public class DialogPanels
{

    public void initClosemainAppDialog(final Stage primaryStage)
    {

        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event)
            {
                event.consume(); // Do nothing on close request

                // Dialog Stage init
                final Stage dialog = new Stage();
                // If you want to freeze the background during dialog appearence set Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL
                // or to allow clicking on the mainstage components set Modality.NONE
                // and set dialog.showAndWait();
                dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);

                // Frage - Label
                Label label = new Label("Exit from the program");

                // Button "Yes"
                Button okBtn = new Button("Yes");
                okBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                    {
                        //primaryStage.close();
                        //dialog.close();
                        //Platform.exit();    
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });

                // Button "No"
                Button cancelBtn = new Button("No");
                cancelBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                    {
                        primaryStage.show();
                        dialog.close();
                    }
                });

                // Layout for the Button
                HBox hbox = new HBox();
                hbox.setSpacing(10);
                hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                hbox.getChildren().add(okBtn);
                hbox.getChildren().add(cancelBtn);

                // Layout for the Label and hBox
                VBox vbox = new VBox();
                vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                vbox.setSpacing(10);
                vbox.getChildren().add(label);
                vbox.getChildren().add(hbox);

                // Stage
                Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 450, 150, Color.WHITESMOKE);
                dialog.setScene(scene);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I want to add image and to make it to look like this:

[image]

But I admin that it's too complex for my short knowledge to get the appropriate result. Can you show me how I can split the dialog, add second background and make my code to look the same as this example please?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [ControlsFX project](http://fxexperience.com/2013/06/announcing-controlsfx-8-0-0-final/), they have some sophisticated dialogs and it's open source, so you can look up how it's done. For example, your dialog looks like this confirmation dialog of ControlsFX:

[image]

There is also support for custom dialogs.

€dit: 
With the "show Masthead" option enabled it actually looks exactly like it:

[image]